# How is individual service identified from multiple services on a single machine in port forwarding

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, ports

Suppose I have a router with external ip address as 123.123.123.123 and within that router I have 5 devices connected one of them being a server which has been assigned a private ip address as 192.168.1.1. 
One important thing is that the server on my private network is running multiple services such as HTTP at port 80, ftp at 21, mail at 60,etc. 
With that now I've port forwarded my router so that external any request to ip address 123.123.123.123 on port 900(any arbitrary port chosen by me) would redirect the request to my server at 192.168.1.1 thats hosting multiple services.
Now imagine that a distant away user types in address 123.123.123.123:900 in the address bar of his browser. So the question is that which service of the server will be invoked as no port number regarding the server's service has been mentioned.
Kindly help .

Comment: In port forwarding, you forward a port to a port. So, you need to choose to which port on the local interface you forward the port 900 on the external interface. You can't forward from one port to multiple ports, unless you are able to tell the firewall from some other information than the port number to forward the request to.

Comment: In port forwarding, you forward a port to a port. Really ?. Because where ever I read about port forwarding it stated that you actually map and internal ip address to a port number

Comment: Please do quote/link one such source.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding Wiki says so bro. Atleast what   I've understood.

Comment: But even if I agree to what you say that " we forward a port to a port " then under port forwarding menu it asks me a range of ports that I need to forward and just one ip address that would be contacted in case any of those ports in the range are called. Then how would a my servers internal ports will be managed.

Comment: "[port forwarding] redirects a communication request from one address and port number combination to another". To me that is saying that it takes one pair (address, port) and redirects that to another such pair. Note the word "combination"...

Comment: If there is no option to select the destination port, then (whatever you are using to configure this) assumes that the destination port number is the same as the source port number.

Comment: I agree with the combination. In this case the request combination would be 123.123.123.123:900 . This would take the request to my router which on reading port 900 would take the request to the server 192.168.1.1 . On that server which service will be called ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32351/discussion-between-zagrimsan-and-shivam-aggarwal).

Comment: *On that server which service will be called ?* Only the one listening on port 900. On any given port, you can only  have **one**service listening. That's why you must forward port 901 to port 5550, port 902 to port 7765, and so on:**one to one**.

Comment: Lets take the analogy that I have two web servers A and B both of which run HTTP service at port 80. Now since in port forwarding I can only bind one port(or a range) to one ip address so I've forwarded port 80 to server A . But now how will the external user access my server B since I have already forwarded port 80 to A.

Comment: @zagrimsan Sir need your help regarding basics of sockets. Please do inform me when get some time, I would like to have a chat with you on the same :) .

Comment: I suggest you go and post new questions on the site (that's what it is for!), I'm not likely to be available for chat anytime soon....

Comment: @zagrimsan Sir I've already asked a the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690843/creating-a-socket-vs-creating-a-connection/34691088?noredirect=1#comment57130168_34691088 but none is able to answer me. I would be really glad if you could :D .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use port forwarding you have to declare the *outside port* and *inside port*.

You can match for example *outside port 900* to *inside port 80*.

If you simply open port 900 on the router, and don't configure the port on the server side,then most likely will be the same port number.